# Radical ideal of not necessarily Noetherian ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local integral domain (not necessarily Noetherian) with Krull dimension 1. Pick an element $\eta \in \mathfrak{m}$. How can I show that $I=(\eta)$ is a primary ideal? In other words, how can we shows that the radical of $I$ is $\mathfrak{m}$?

This is came from the argument of proof of Theorem 10.7 in Matsumura showing that a valuation ring $R$ has Krull dimension 1 iff the rank of value group $G$ of $R$ is 1. Any hints or ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I=0$ there is nothing to prove. Otherwise note that the the radical $\sqrt{I}$ is the intersection of the prime ideals containing $I$. But since $A$ is a local integral domain of dimension $1$ the only prime ideal containing $I$ is $\frak{m}$, so $\sqrt{I}=\frak{m}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!